# Qt Creator: copy .exe output into a folder

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5, qmake

I am sorry if the question was already asked but after some research I couldn't find an answer. I want to copy the .exe of a project into a folder automatically.

I am using Qt creator 5.0.1 MSCV2010 and it always makes two outputs: release and debug.

For example, I want the `/release/project.exe` to be in `/release/exec/project.exe`.

I saw I can copy file like .dll with in a .pro with:

```
INSTALLS =
```

But it only work with files which already exist, or the .exe is generated after the compilation. I think I can specify this into:

```
projects settings->Build compilation->step Make : jom.exe in C:\path\to\project-release
```

But I don't know what argument is needed,
Regards

Comment: Note that *qmake* and Qt Creator are two different things. They are often user together, but do not depend on each others either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can use `DLLDESTDIR` variable which specifies where to copy the target dll or exe. Just add this to your .pro :

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release): DLLDESTDIR +=  $$PWD/../exec
```

On Linux you can use `QMAKE_POST_LINK` variable which contains the command to execute after linking the TARGET together. So it is like:

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release): QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(cp project $$PWD/../exec)
```

Here `project` is the name of the target file which you provide by `TARGET = project`

These will copy the executable binary to a directory named `exec`  one level upper than the program working directory. You can have your arbitrary path.

Comment: Thank you very much, the first command works fine for me. I did'nt know this instruction for a .pro but it will be useful in the futur.

Answer (score 0):

add a custom build step with the command an parameters

for windows (assuming you are doing this for the release build):

```
xcopy
Release\<target.exe> path\to\destination\file.exe /Y
%{buildDir}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I couldn't find any [variable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html) that points the target_path. So I defined it:

```
### to copy target file to build folder
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    TARGET_PATH = $$OUT_PWD/debug
}
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    TARGET_PATH = $$OUT_PWD/release
}

win32: QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy /y "$$shell_path($$TARGET_PATH/app_name.exe)" "$$shell_path($$PWD/../build/)"
unix: QMAKE_POST_LINK += cp "$$shell_path($$TARGET_PATH/app_name)" "$$shell_path($$PWD/../build/)"
```