# How to get the target directory in PRO file

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I am building an application in Debug mode, how to get the target directory in pro file.
I didnt explicitly mentioned the target directory using "DESTDIR"

```
    CORE_API_PATH = $$PWD/../Bin
    SEPARATOR = "/"

    QT       += core gui xml widgets printsupport svg

    greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

    TARGET = Cinemas
    TEMPLATE = app

    RC_ICONS += cinemas-icon.ico

    qtHaveModule(opengl) {
        DEFINES += QT_OPENGL_SUPPORT
        QT += opengl
    }

    LIBS += -lQt5Concurrent -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lglut32 -LC:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\glut -LC:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\mingw482_32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\glu32


    win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += "$$quote($${CORE_API_PATH}/Release/CoreApi.dll)"
    else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release):  LIBS += "$$quote($${CORE_API_PATH}/Debug/CoreApiD.dll)"

    win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/SSH/lib/ -lssh2
    else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/SSH/lib/ -lssh2
    else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/SSH/lib/ -lssh2

    win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/3rdparty/qwt/lib/ -lqwt
    else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/3rdparty/qwt/lib/ -lqwtd
    else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/qwt/lib/ -libqwt


    QT += concurrent network

    CONFIG += c++11

    RESOURCES += \
        cinemasresource.qrc

    FORMS += \
```

I want to copy the app.exe from the current folder to some other folder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23605257/